# How to make the LibGDX GLSurfaceView transparent so that we can see the Android ImageView behind it?

Tags: android, libgdx

The basic premise is that I have 2 Android Views... A background view that fills the screen (`ImageView` in this case), and a `LibGDX GLSurfaceView` that is in the foreground, and is the `LibGDX` application.  I want to punch a hole in the `LibGDX GLSurfaceView`, so that I can see the background `ImageView` show through.  ie, the `LibGDX` part is behaving like an overlay.  Sadly I cannot get this to work at all.  I've stripped away all the code to leave just the bare necessities that hopefully demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

In the full application, it is an Android application where the background `View` is a Video, and the foreground, being rendered by `LibGdx` is a set of video controls, that needs to be overlaid on the video.

```
public class MiniClientGDXTestActivity extends AndroidApplication implements ApplicationListener {
    @Bind(R.id.surface)
    FrameLayout uiFrameHolder;

    Stage stage;
    Batch batch;
    Camera camera;
    Viewport viewport;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;


    private View miniClientView;

    public MiniClientGDXTestActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        hideSystemUI(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.miniclientgltest_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        //cfg.useGL20 = false;
        // we need to change the default pixel format - since it does not include an alpha channel
        // we need the alpha channel so the camera preview will be seen behind the GL scene
        cfg.r = 8;
        cfg.g = 8;
        cfg.b = 8;
        cfg.a = 8;

        miniClientView = initializeForView(this, cfg);

        if (graphics.getView() instanceof SurfaceView) {
            SurfaceView glView = (SurfaceView) graphics.getView();
            glView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
            // force alpha channel - I'm not sure we need this as the GL surface is already using alpha channel
            glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        uiFrameHolder.addView(miniClientView);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new StretchViewport(1920, 1080, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        batch = stage.getBatch();
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
        Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().setWorldSize(1920, 1080);
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
        Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // draw whatever we have on the stage
        stage.draw();

        // draw red rectangle
        drawRect(10, 10, 1000, 1000);

        // draw a blue box
        fillRect(50, 50, 800, 800);

        // punch a hole in the surface (ie, clear an area) so that we can see the view that is
        // behind this view
        clearRect(200, 200, 1600, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    public void drawRect(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    public void fillRect(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    public void clearRect(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
//                Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
//                Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.CLEAR);
        shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);
        shapeRenderer.end();

//                Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    }

}
```

And here's the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- to see if we can see this -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/background"/>

        <!-- gdx gets added here -->
    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `View` is not part of the LibGDX framework. And you are not putting anything on the stage but you are drawing the stage. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Anyway, if you are looking to "punch holes" in something I guess your only option is to use images and clipping masks. https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking

Comment: I get that this sample doesn't do much, because I stripped away everything that is does do, to illustrate the point.  ie, I have 2 Android View.. An  ImageView that is a background and a GLSurfaceView that is LibGDX.  I want to punch a hole in the GLSurfaceView to see a part of the background image.  I took this libgdx as a base tutorial. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera  I am not trying to mask 2 LibGDX textures/pimaps.   For the most part, this is an android + GLSurfaceView issue (I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that calling `setZOrderOnTop` with using `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` did the trick.

```
    if (graphics.getView() instanceof SurfaceView) {
        GLSurfaceView glView = (GLSurfaceView) graphics.getView();
        glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }
```

now when the `clearRect` method is called it will punch a hole in the GLSurfaceView to see the Android view that is below.